# Jquery найти первые 3 слова и изменить стили

Tags: jquery

Есть много строк с примерно следующим содержанием:

`Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 1 кабинет 20`

Как найти во всех строках  первые три слова и установить стиль текста жирный?

я разбил строку на массив, а дальше что делать не могу сообразить...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user_str = $(".option-user").text();
    var user_parse = user_str.split(' ', 3);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы уже почти все сделали, я предлагаю первые 3 слова обернуть в тег `b`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.option-user').each(function() {
    var user = $(this);
    var userStr = user.text() || '';
    var userParse = userStr.split(' ').map(function(str, index) {
      if (index > 2) return str;
      return '<b>' + str + '</b>';
    });
    user.html(userParse.join(' '));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 1 кабинет 20</div>
<div class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 2 кабинет 20</div>
<div class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 3 кабинет 20</div>
<div class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 4 кабинет 20</div>
```

**для селекта**
Да, вы правы

> опция select'a,а как вы знаете теги внутри селекта не работают

но в вопросе о том что это `select` ничего не сказано

для того чтобы кастомизировать `select` обычно используют обертки из дивов, спанов и жс, если лень писать самому, то можно воcпользоваться готовым решением, например [select2](https://select2.org/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var generateTemplate = function(state) {
    var userParse = state.text.split(' ').map(function(str, index) {
      if (index > 2) return str;
      return '<b>' + str + '</b>';
    });
    return $('<div>' + userParse.join(' ') + '</div>');
  };
  $('select').select2({
    templateResult: generateTemplate,
    templateSelection: generateTemplate
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 1 кабинет 20</option>
  <option class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 2 кабинет 20</option>
  <option class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 3 кабинет 20</option>
  <option class="option-user">Иванова Мария Сергеевна здание 4 кабинет 20</option>
</select>
```

Comment: и почему все тут решили, что у ТС есть много дивов `.option-user` ? хотя написано было просто, про "много строк". Никто не говорил, про какую-то ни было разметку. приведен просто текст. Вот и рассматривайте что там просто много текстовых строк.

Comment: @teran , в таком виде вопрос чуть легче решается... ну и, если блок всего один, обычно в него удобнее тыкать через id, а не class)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но такой варианта не подходит. Да он вставляет тег b в разметку, но дело в том что `class="option-user"` 'это опция select'a,а как вы знаете теги внутри селекта не работают. Можно ли  как-то поменять? css стиль

Comment: @BorsheC посмотрите, я изменил свой ответ

Comment: Я использую этот мультиселект http://loudev.com/. И в его документации нет ни слова как менять шаблон(

Comment: @BorsheC в этом плагине и не получится поменять шаблон